# "ValueError: Asked to retrieve element 0, but the Sequence has length 0" in Convolutional Neural Network

Tags: python-3.x, keras, conv-neural-network

I am using this code: https://github.com/gsurma/image_classifier/blob/master/ImageClassifierCNN.ipynb but I get this error: `ValueError: Asked to retrieve element 0, but the Sequence has length 0` on this line: `probabilities = model.predict_generator(test_generator, TEST_SIZE)` . I followed this suggestion: [How can I get rid of getting error through test generator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63738213/how-can-i-get-rid-of-getting-error-through-test-generator) and I changed the above line to this: `probabilities = model.predict(test_generator, TEST_SIZE)` but does not work! And this: [ValueError: Asked to retrieve element 0, but the Sequence has length 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67806987/valueerror-asked-to-retrieve-element-0-but-the-sequence-has-length-0) has no solution for my case. Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching I have found that I need to include 2 folders inside "test" folder, where the folder names are "cat" and "dog". In order to see all the test images I changed `TEST_SIZE = ...` to the total number of the images inside the 2 folders under "test" folder.